# Customized Buttons on a UIActionsheet

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiactionsheet

I am trying to create a `UIActionsheet` with several buttons as options.

1. Is it possible?.
2. If it is, will apple let in onto apps store. I have seen in some blogs that these types of windows are rejected?
3. if not possible is there an alternative to `UIActionsheet`, that will achieve similar functionallity?.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible and I don't think Apple will reject it (why would they ?).

Answer (score 0):

1. Action sheet is like a UIView you can add anything in that. Yes! you can create a UIActionsheet as you specified.
2. Apple will not be rejecting if it is customized. it may be due to some other issues.
3. Refer answer 1. Why cant you use a normal UIView.

To know more about UIActionsheet read the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LocateMe/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: Thanks I thought it must be possible. I currently have  UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
          initWithTitle:nil
          delegate:self
          cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
          destructiveButtonTitle:@"Undo"
          otherButtonTitles:@"Watch A Video", @"Share with Friends", @"Save to My Favorites",nil];
From a sample how do I get two rows of buttons like in the example?

Comment: Just create buttons and add as a subview to the Actionsheet

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but I am going round in circles with this.

Comment: Here is the code it just gives me a black heading http://www.uploadimage.co.uk/images/81541977825436699220.png

Comment: If anyone is trying to do what I was with the UIActionsheet. Don't, it is considered an incorrect use of UIActionsheet and you app will not be accepted. Use a UIView in a popover.